# How do you write a test program in Java?

Tags: java

I am a beginner programmer, and i really have no idea what is going in in my class most of the time. I am given this project to do,and I understand what is being asked but I have no idea how to write it. so here is the strategy all help is appreciated. I have the two panes set up for testing in Eclipse that's about it.

1. checking for no arguments
2. checking for invalid arguments
3. checking valid arguments with no input
4. checking valid arguments with a line that matches
5. "" with a line that doesn't match
6. check valid argument with 2 lines

with information similar to this

```
rs3934834,1,1045729
```

Apparently we are supposed to read the line, check to see if the last number is between the first two in range and if so print it out.

Pseudo code:

```
While more lines in standard input 
  read line
  break lines into name, chromosome, position
  if chromosome is same as c
  if position is in range
    then print
```

Comment: hey try to refer some tutorial for java....because nobody here will right code for you....

Comment: The answer can be found by reading books such as [JUnit in Action](http://www.amazon.com/JUnit-Action-Vincent-Massol/dp/1930110995). It's a subject unto itself, and beyond the scope of a simple Q/A format such as this forum. However, your desire to write tests is a good one. I wish you luck.

Comment: some of the answers youve received sound a little harsh to me, youve got some things right. its ok to admit you dont know how to do it, its ok to start with pseudocode and divide it into subtasks, its ok to ask others for help (usually helps to analyze and make the problem clearer in your own mind). Now how about posting some code  so we can help you better?

Answer (score 0):

For a start, there should be an array of strings, usually called `args`, as a parameter to your application's main method, so you can use that for all your argument checks.

The standard input is `System.in` and I seem to recall there being some methods on that to read lines etc, perhaps you can check the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) for that.

Also, you won't make too many friends on stackoverflow by asking people to do your homework for you.  I hope my very brief suggestions can point you in the right direction... Now take a look over your course notes as they will no doubt contain all, or at least most, of the answers you need to do your homework!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your question, here what you can do: (not a solution but just the hint)

1) Use [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class to read your command line input. Read line by line.

2) Use [String.split(",")](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method on each line of input to split the `String` on comma, this will give you `String[ ]`.

3) Now check for the desired conditions on `input, chromosome and position`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to read in a users line, I'd suggest a pretty simple technique of importing a scanner which will read input for you.

Paste this at the top of your class: 
import java.util.*;

then in your main method, type in:

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
.

Now you've imported and created a "scanner" called input. What you're going to want to do in order to read in a line from the user is print any sort of message along the lines of "Please input your text: ", and on the next line of code use your scanner ,called input, to set the users input equal to a string that you'll create.